# elasticsearch exclude results with value

Tags: elasticsearch

How can i perform a search excluding results where a field has a specific value?

I have a database of Reddit comments and i want to find Bitcoin mentions, but exclude the bitcoin subreddit.

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true&size=100' -d '
{
    "filtered": {
        "query" : {
            "match": {
                "body": "bitcoin"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "not": {
                "term": {
                    "subreddit": "bitcoin"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}'
```

The error is to long to post here. https://gist.github.com/kylelk/feca416156712eebad3e

Comment: Whats wrong with the query? what you get?

Comment: It is not complete, copy all the error.

Comment: @progrrammer The error was to long, here is the gist https://gist.github.com/kylelk/feca416156712eebad3e  Thank You

Comment: He probably got a 400 Bad request

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is silly error,

You have to include filtered query inside query . Here is modification

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "body": "bitcoin"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "not": {
               "term": {
                  "subreddit": "bitcoin"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Not valid for Elasticsearch 5.x - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519806/no-query-registered-for-filtered