# Using `not` filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in ElasticSearch. I am trying to filter out documents where the field `message_class` equals 'SE'.

I have referred to [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353564/elasticsearch-exclude-results-with-value), amongst other things, but the query below still returns documents that have the field `message_class` equaling 'SE'.

What is the correct way to use the `not` filter?

```
POST _search
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "filter":{  
            "not":{  
               "term":{  
                  "message_class":"SE"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The `_mapping` for the field `message_class` shows:

```
    "message_class" : {
      "full_name" : "message_class", "mapping" : {"message_class":{"type":"string"}}
    }
```

Comment: What is your mapping for the `message_class` field ? To use a `term` filter, you usually need a non-analyzed field.

Comment: @mguillermin I have added the information to the question, thanks. Not sure how to interpret it though. Would appreciate your help there. What other filter could I use instead?

Comment: Just a note: in general you should avoid using `not` filter - use `bool` filter with `must_not` clause instead http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the term query , the analyzer is not applied on your query. Assuming that lowercase filter is applied , the following should work fine -

```
POST _search
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "filter":{  
            "not":{  
               "term":{  
                  "message_class":"se"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```