# Remove documents with lowest relevancy in match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to remove documents with lowest relevancy in match query. Is there any other way to do this beside score t?

**Use case:**

Suppose we have :-

*index: office
doctype: employee
post(field): Account officer, account manager, accountant, chief acc etc which are different documents.*

Now I search "account" in a match query against all the docs in the "post" field.

Let's say "chief acc" value for "post" field in above doc is 'least relavant'.

I want to exclude those very less relevant matches in search results list.

I tried by using score of results but I think that is not feasible. Is there any other way to achieve this beside score??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by having a filtered query inside your query:

```
POST _search
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "filter":{  
            "not":{  
               "term":{  
                  "post":"chief acc"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you're using ES 5.0 you have to use [must_not](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) filter instead of `not`:

```
"must_not" : {
        "term" : { "post" : "chief acc" }
      }
```

Maybe you could have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353564/elasticsearch-exclude-results-with-value) as well. Hope it helps!