# Why am I getting NaN from an elasticsearch aggregate query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the query below, occasionally I receive a "NaN" response (see the response below the query).

I'm assuming that, occasionally, some invalid data gets in to the "amount" field (the one being aggregated).  If that is a valid assumption, how can I find those documents with the invalid "amount" fields so I can troubleshoot them?

If that's not a valid assumption, how do I troubleshoot the occasional "NaN" value being returned?

REQUEST:

```
POST /_msearch
{
  "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "index": [
    "view-2017-10-22",
    "view-2017-10-23"
  ]
}
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "handling-time": {
              "gte": "1508706273585",
              "lte": "1508792673586",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "+page:\"checkout order confirmation\" +pageType:\"d\""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "1h",
        "field": "time",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "1508706273585",
          "max": "1508792673586"
        },
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "took": 12,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 44587,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "2": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "1": {
                "value": "NaN"
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508706000000",
              "key": 1508706000000,
              "doc_count": 2915
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 300203.74
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508709600000",
              "key": 1508709600000,
              "doc_count": 2851
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 348139.5600000001
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508713200000",
              "key": 1508713200000,
              "doc_count": 3197
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": "NaN"
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508716800000",
              "key": 1508716800000,
              "doc_count": 3449
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": "NaN"
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508720400000",
              "key": 1508720400000,
              "doc_count": 3482
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 364449.60999999987
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508724000000",
              "key": 1508724000000,
              "doc_count": 3103
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 334914.68
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508727600000",
              "key": 1508727600000,
              "doc_count": 2722
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 315368.09000000014
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508731200000",
              "key": 1508731200000,
              "doc_count": 2161
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 102244.34
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508734800000",
              "key": 1508734800000,
              "doc_count": 742
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 37178.63
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508738400000",
              "key": 1508738400000,
              "doc_count": 333
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 25345.68
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508742000000",
              "key": 1508742000000,
              "doc_count": 233
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 85454.47000000002
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508745600000",
              "key": 1508745600000,
              "doc_count": 477
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 24102.719999999994
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508749200000",
              "key": 1508749200000,
              "doc_count": 195
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 23352.309999999994
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508752800000",
              "key": 1508752800000,
              "doc_count": 294
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 44353.409999999996
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508756400000",
              "key": 1508756400000,
              "doc_count": 450
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 80129.89999999998
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508760000000",
              "key": 1508760000000,
              "doc_count": 867
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 122797.11
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508763600000",
              "key": 1508763600000,
              "doc_count": 1330
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 157442.29000000004
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508767200000",
              "key": 1508767200000,
              "doc_count": 1872
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 198831.71
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508770800000",
              "key": 1508770800000,
              "doc_count": 2251
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 218384.08000000002
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508774400000",
              "key": 1508774400000,
              "doc_count": 2305
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 229829.22000000006
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508778000000",
              "key": 1508778000000,
              "doc_count": 2381
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 217157.56000000006
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508781600000",
              "key": 1508781600000,
              "doc_count": 2433
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 208877.13
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508785200000",
              "key": 1508785200000,
              "doc_count": 2223
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": "NaN"
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508788800000",
              "key": 1508788800000,
              "doc_count": 2166
            },
            {
              "1": {
                "value": 18268.14
              },
              "key_as_string": "1508792400000",
              "key": 1508792400000,
              "doc_count": 155
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "status": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show your mapping? GET /_msearch/_mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search for `<fieldName>:NaN` (on numeric fields) to find numbers that are set to NaN.

Obviously, once you find those, you can either fix the root cause of the field being set to NaN, or you can exclude those records from the aggregation by adding a `-<fieldName>:NaN` to the query.

(It turns out that the input was feeding in some garbage characters once in every few million documents.)

Comment: To exclude a field, you can try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353564/elasticsearch-exclude-results-with-value